# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') when calling from an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im really stuck on a problem - if you run the code below you will get an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
".

When i console log out the "items" var I get 2 results as shown here:
[image]

The problem lies within the first result as it is empty. But can someone explain to me why this result is empty and why it produces 2 results?

This code was taken directly from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) and modified to suit what is returned from the API. Please consider running this code so you can see what i mean.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://www.7timer.info/bin/api.pl?lon=113.17&lat=23.09&product=astro&output=json")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
      setIsLoaded(true);
       setItems(result); 
    },
    // Note: it's important to handle errors here
    // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
    // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
    (error) => {
      setIsLoaded(true);
      setError(error);
    }
  )
  }, [])


  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
return (
  <ul>
    {items.dataseries.map(item => (
       {console.log(item)}
    ))}
</ul>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your `items` state var doesn't have the attribute `dataseries` on first load. You will need to check it in the render function before rendering it with `map`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes which I could see

1. One being the data you're fetching is an object while you're setting it initially to be an array and you're also using map function which can only be used on arrays.
2. Initially your array doesn't contain `dataseries` also you can't access property like that in an array right (because array have indexes by which we get the there value).

So what you could do is instead set this function to be like this

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch("http://www.7timer.info/bin/api.pllon=113.17&lat=23.09&product=astro&output=json")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(
  (result) => {
  setIsLoaded(true);
   setItems(result.dataseries); 
},
// Note: it's important to handle errors here
// instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
// exceptions from actual bugs in components.
  (error) => {
    setIsLoaded(true);
    setError(error);
  }
)}, [])
```

And return function to be something like this

```
return (
  <ul>
    {items.map(item => (
      {console.log(item)}
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

Comment: Perfect. You're answer solved my issue. But I'm curious, do you know why the value gets output twice? Also if I set the state to be an object and store result, why can't I access items.dataseries in the map function?

Comment: Yeah because React doesn't work in a way that first it waits for all requests to be fetched and then renders the content. Whenever the component gets mounts, it renders with whatever is available.
So initially your items point to an empty array, there array.map worked but when array got changed to object (when data got fetched and setState was called) it no longer had the map function as objects don't support map function.
Also, that's the reason it outputs twice, because the first time when component got mounted and then the second time when setState was called and component got rerender.

Answer (score 0):

Items is an array not the object eg [{...}, {...}] , desiredseries is inside object, not items.

```
 <ul>
        {items.map(item => item.dataseries.map(ds=> (
           {console.log(ds)}
        )))}
    </ul>
```